# Voice Recording SDK for Windows Mobile 6.5 Classic

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5

I am building Voice recording application for Windows Mobile 6.5 Classic device, i was searching for ready made SDK\library, but i haven't found SDK or any recording library. Do you have any suggestion ?

Thanks
Suresh

Answer (score 2):

For voice recording on WM 6.5 we can call API though P/Invoke in C#.

I just found a document to tell us how to use P/Invoke to use audio interface in our project, also it has codes you can download in it.

[Recording and Playing Sound with the Waveform Audio Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446573.aspx)

I hope my suggestions can help you to solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks, will check it.